# HABTM collection_singular_ids method not working as expected on rails4.2.0.beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model User that has_and_belongs_to_many Domain

On rails 4.0.3 and 4.1.7, I'm able to set a user's domains when I create the User like this:

```
user = User.new
user.domain_ids = [1, 2, 3]
user.save!
```

However on rails 4.2.0.beta4 this doesn't work anymore, the following exception is raised from PG when I attempt to save the user.

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "domain_ids" of relation "users" does not exist
```

Since it concerns a beta version of rails I'm tempted to call it a regression bug but I would like to be sure I'm not missing something ? Can anyone confirm this behavior?

Comment: In Rails 4.2.0.beta4, can you do `user.domains`? or does it produce the same error, too?

Comment: No, at work. Pulling some code from remote and waiting for it to finish. :P

Comment: Opps!.. So productive you are both in SO and at work.. Don't ask me the same question.. :p

Comment: @User089247 yes user.domains works on Rails 4.2.0.beta4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's possible to work in the User model, as it should only work on the Join model, as you can see by the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).
Although the more cleaner (in terms of code readability) it's to use the relation and then [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to get the desired columns, in you case `id`

```
User.domains.pluck(:id)
```